# Is it possible to attach and NFS (NetApp files) volume to an Azure Container Instance?

Tags: azure, nfs, azure-container-instances

I have an NFS server (NetApp files) which I wish to mount as a volume on an Azure Container Instance. Is this possible?

I need to do this programmatically and the [az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) appears not to have any options for it.

I can launch the container in the same vnet as the NFS server but I can't then mount the volume as far as I can tell.

I am able to access the volume from within an AKS cluster I run but I was hoping to keep this bit of functionality outside of the cluster.

I also haven't found any workaround (such as mounting the volume *inside* the container).

Any suggestions? Is this impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a great question. I am not 100% sure and will have to test to confirm as I am not overly familiar with NetApp in Azure. However if it is possible, you would use the doc for mapping file shares located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it's possible to mount a volume of Azure NetApp Files to an Azure Container Instance. Not to do this in programming or use Azure CLI, but to create a custom Docker image with some drivers like SAMBA/CIFS which will helps to mount a NFS volume as a Docker volume.

As references, you can follow the steps and refer to the related documents below.

1. The blog [Using a SAMBA/CIFS mount as a docker volume](https://kartoza.com/en/blog/using-a-sambacifs-mount-as-a-docker-volume/) introduces the base idea. And the other blog [Mount AWS EFS, NFS or CIFS/Samba volumes in Docker](https://dzone.com/articles/mount-aws-efs-nfs-or-cifssamba-volumes-in-docker) also be useful at here.
2. Follow the offical document [Tutorial: Create a container image for deployment to Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-app) to know how to create a container image.
3. The offical document [Mount or unmount a volume for Windows or Linux virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/azure-netapp-files-mount-unmount-volumes-for-virtual-machines) shows the `Mount instructions` of Azure NetApp Files to help to mount a volume to a Linux instance which be a Docker instance of a custom image you need to build.

Then, if the image has been built, you can try to deploy it as Azure Container Instance. For doing these, please refer to the two offical documents [Tutorial: Deploy an Azure container registry and push a container image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-acr) and [Tutorial: Deploy a container application to Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-deploy-app).

Comment: Thanks, @peter-pan . This is a bit too involved for what I'm trying to achieve so I've not tested but I'm gonna go ahead and mark as correct. I hope Azure make this simpler (and reliable) in the near future.

Comment: @Peter-Pan: I'm not sure this would actually work, unless I misunderstand your approach. ACI currently only supports Azure File CIFS mounts, not NFS mounts.